# Uploading files suddenly stops while uploading

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload files to firebase-storage and the upload starts because I can see the logs but then just stops.

I open up the rules so I can upload regardless of authentication. And the simulator works fine

```
  var metadata = {
    contentType: 'audio/*'
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  var uploader = document.getElementById("uploader");
  var fileButton = document.getElementById("music_files");


  uploadBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var file = document.getElementById("music_files").files;

    var uploadTask = storageRef.child('music/' + file[0].name).put(file[0], metadata);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {

  // A full list of error codes is available at
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
      break;
  }
}, function() {
  // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});


  });
```

I expect to have constant logs until 100% and then have the url. But now Sometimes it stops at 30s/40s/50s% and other starts and dont show more progress after(0%)

Comment: Have you checked in the browser's developer tools? The state of the request can usually be tracked to determine the point of failure.

Comment: the network tab?

Comment: In most modern browsers, yes.

Comment: Everything has a 200 code of okay. I canged PCs and the problem remains

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can share the output of the error you are getting